# How to optimization two equations

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have not taken any optimization course yet.

I have the equation:

(x+y)z * C1

where C1 is a constant and I want to maximize it while the following equation:

x+y+z+xz * C2

that should be minimized ( C2 is a constant).

I should mention that x,y,z,C1 and C2 are positive. 0.001< C1 <0.05 and 0.001< C2 <0.05

How can I obtain the optimized solution? 
Any code in MATLAB is appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask], this is way too broad, and without ANY input from your side, it'll be hard for anyone to give you an answer, without actually doing your work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a multi-objective (or multi-criteria) problem. It does not have one single optimal solution, but rather a a whole set of solutions. Often the solution set is depicted by a graph (efficient frontier). Some rather mathy background can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization. This link has info about Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/multiobjective-optimization.html.

Comment: Thank you Erwin for your Answer.